# make a git branch always ahead of another branch

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have two git branch 258_roomMap and MEM_roomMap.

- MEM_roomMap is my working branch including a specific file requested
  by a client.
- 258_roomMap is a public branch with one more commit (always
  the same) that remove this specific file.

I want 258_roomMap to always stay on top of MEM_roomMap with that commit. Is there a way to achieve that without having to rebase every time I do something in the working branch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, just to make sure, if `258_roomMap` was branched off of `MEM_roomMap` at a point when `MEM_roomMap` already contained the file that you talk about, and `258_roomMap` is public, then people can access a previous state of that file. This is because a git keeps track of the development **history**.

That said, to do what you want, you can just create a `post-commit` hook. The hook will check to make sure the commit was made on `MEM_roomMap`. If it was, you'll `cherry-pick` it to `258_roomMap` and, in doing so, will `git rm` the client's file and `git commit --amend` the `cherry-pick`ed commit.

Comment: I don't mind the file being accessible. I only mind if this file in there by default, thanks for the answer